# How can I vertically centre this image in a RelativeLayout?

Tags: android

How can I vertically centre the image in the example depicted below?

[image]

I need it to look like this:

[image]

The layout I'm using is as follows:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutBranding"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/banner"
        android:layout_margin="7dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgInstallerLogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logonarrow"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtInstallerName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="[Installer Description]"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgInstallerLogo"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtIntallerPhone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="[Installer Phone Number]"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtInstallerName"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgInstallerLogo" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` row.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` from xml in ImageView.

Updated code

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgInstallerLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logonarrow"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` from your ImageView.

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgInstallerLogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logonarrow"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgInstallerLogo"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"    
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logonarrow" />
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutBranding"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/banner"
        android:layout_margin="7dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgInstallerLogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logonarrow"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtInstallerName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="[Installer Description]"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgInstallerLogo"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtIntallerPhone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="[Installer Phone Number]"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtInstallerName"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgInstallerLogo" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ***android:layout_alignParentTop="true"*** from your ImageView.